# Grouping the same letters within a code in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, for-loop, group-by

I am trying to write a code where it outputs the number of consecutive letters that come after one another as it is running through `list_`. So all the outputs will start with 1 consecutive number followed by a second and a third if the following value is equivalent. So for example the order `['b','b','b',r]`  would produce the output of `1,2,3,1` as the consecutive list is disrupt by the upcoming `r` in the loop so it goes back to 1 consecutive int from 3.

Code for the consecutive `b`s and `r`s

```
list_ = ['b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r']
for k, gp in groupby(list_):
    print(k,list(gp))
```

Comment: could you explain this better?

Comment: You talk about numbers, but show string inputs. Then you go about the `maximum in each list at each certain point`. What does `maximum` mean? From your example I would guess the size, which you get when doing `len(list(gp))`.  Please provide a better explanation of what you want, and a clear (and concise) example. `This` input leads to `that` output.

Comment: @coderoftheday  I have updated the details. Sorry for the confusion. if you guys could read the description again that would be great.

Comment: @Thymen  have updated the details. Sorry for the confusion. if you guys could read the description again that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is `rle`:

What you are looking for is:

```
from itertools import groupby
rle = lambda x : [k for i,j in groupby(x) for k in range(1,len(list(j)) + 1)]
print(rle(['b','b','b','r']))
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: For all of you having to google `rle`, it stands for `Run-length encoding`. In the answer the `rle` determines the group size of consecutive letters, then by using `range` he can output the increasing count that the OP asks for.

Comment: Is assigned an `lambda` anonymous function to a alias name consider `good` Python practice?  (know it's working in this case).  Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner:

```
alist = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'r']
print([idx for k, group in itertools.groupby(alist)
   for idx, v in enumerate(group, start=1)])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```